# Здравствуйте, как получить громкость двух файлов и присвоить им среднюю громкость?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, аудио, react-native, web-audio

Например есть 2 файла в массиве,у первого громкость трека -очень громкая, у другого-тихая, нужно сделать обоим громкость среднюю.

Comment: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytefrequencydata, а также посмотрите это https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/maxDecibels

Comment: При чём AnaliseNode, если об анализаторе спектра речь не идёт. Для самого простого решения с громкостью нужна функция WebAudio Api cteateGain(). С помощью неё можно установить любую громкость. Если всё же хотите получить громкость исходных файлов, нужна функция decodeAudioData(). Она получает все семплы файла и по разности между самым положительным и самым отрицательным семплами можно определить громкость. Делим эту разницу на два в степени, соответствующей разрядности семплов и получаем значение от 0 до 1 громкости файла. http://tolmatux.strana.de/player.html тутпример использования.

Comment: Там скопируете исходники переделаете его, чтобы он получал громкость.